# Clicking link to website not working but only typing the url

Tags: angular, hyperlink, dns

Clicking on a link to my website (in an e-mail or on LinkedIn) results in 'ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED', but typing in the same address does work...

The website is made in Angular, with a Java/Springboot/SQL back-end server running.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Can you share more details.how do you redirect from email or Linkedin? Do you have a redirected URL?

Comment: seems like browser's dns cache issue.Make sure if you used the same browser in both situations.If not, then one of them should be cache-cleaned

Comment: The redirect is a simple URL typed in an email/post (like www.example.com) which gmail or LinkedIn automatically turns into a hyperlink. I use the same browser both times.